# Spring Boot doesn't create tables in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to generate schema tables based on entities. But tables are not created. What's wrong?

Entity example:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    public String username;
    public String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String username) {
        this(username, username + "pass");
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbtest
spring.datasource.username=vssekorin
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
compile('org.telegram:telegrambots:3.6.1')
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Warning: `GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement`

Comment: can you show the complete log for this "GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
```

in your `application.properties`.

Or you can change this line:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

in

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

More details: [Spring Database initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Answer (score 2):

just change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` from `update` to `create`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

and change spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto from update to create

Comment: Hi @Aziz - welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your answer more than 2.5 years after an answer was provided that accepted by the author of the OP (original post) doesn't seem to add anything new, OR you believe it does, then please edit the accepted answer to add your new insight.

Answer (score 0):

Entity(name="Users")
postgresql can't create a table named user
and

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i created a entities package outside the main application class;

Exemple:

wrong

[image]

correct

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered same problem, in my case it was the fact i created the package model outside of the root folder where Application.java class is situated.